# How to set multiple image in image frame same time in wxpython

Tags: python, gps, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have been develop a gps system. then i am using python and wx python for make GUI. so i have able to show single map part in image viewer. but is is not sufficient. i want to load separate images same time and show them as a single image in my wx python GUI.

How can i do this with wx python?

Comment: maybe you could use [wx.GridSizer](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/layout/) layout manager to put images in cells (see example with buttons in calculator) or you can overwrite [OnEraseBackground](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/) function to freely draw in window/widget.

Comment: Please explain "separate images ... as a single image" better. Do you want to use tiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OnPaint` (in any widget) to draw own elements.

You can draw many images in widget.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(300, 200))

        #self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)

        # two images
        self.image1 = wx.Bitmap("ball-1.png")
        self.image2 = wx.Bitmap("ball-2.png")

        # assign own function to draw widget
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

        self.Show()

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)

        # draw own elements

        width  = self.image1.GetWidth()
        height = self.image1.GetHeight()

        dc.DrawBitmap(self.image1, 0, 0)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.image2, width, 0)

        dc.DrawBitmap(self.image2, 0, height)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.image1, width, height)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = wx.App()
    MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image: ball-1.png] ball-1.png
[image: ball-2.png] ball-2.png

[image: MyFrame.png]